# Two Definitions of Cohomologies

Tags: homology-cohomology

There are two definitions of cohomologies I've found so far: The first (very good to understand) definition is via coboundaries and is very often written as
$$ H^p = {Z^p}/{B^p} ,$$
and the second one is 
$$ H^p = Ext_g^p .$$
I have no clue why they are identical. If the answer is too long its enough to give a source to read it.

I use it in the context of Lie Algebras, so if there is an easier proof only for Lie Algebras, it's enough for me.

EDIT: i have both definitions and they look pretty similar when u use the right complexe(s). But i still cant figure out why the sequence
$ P_2 \overset{d_1}{\rightarrow} P_1 \overset{d_0}{\rightarrow} P_0 \overset{\epsilon}\rightarrow M $

is exact, the rest is clear now. 
Tomorrow i will write the exact definitions to this post (I dont have my work at home)

Comment: Your first equation should be $H^p = Z^p / B^p$.

Comment: thanks i fixed it

Comment: Ext is the cohomology of a chain complex, so once you define your cochairs and boundary operators, you are in. But I don’t think that is the question you want to ask.

Comment: Somehow what _should_ be $H^p=Z^p/B^p$ is not repaired yet, so far as I can see...